# Need to load the excel data to database table on weekly basis automatically

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create table LOADER_TAB (
    i_id,
    i_name,
    risk
);
```

csv file :

```
portal,,
ex portal,,
,,
i_id,i_name,risk
1,a,aa
2,b,bb
3,c,cc
4,d,dd
5,e,ee
6,f,ff
7,g,gg
8,h,hh
9,i,ii
10,j,jj
```

I need to load the excel data to a database table on weekly basis. Currently, I am doing using SQL Loader every time. But is there any other way to automate it? I need to load the data every Monday into the table. I am wondering if this can be done with dbms_scheduler? How I will be able to load the data into the table automatically when I load the excel in the folder on weekly basis ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep using SQL*Loader, then you probably wouldn't use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` (although it is capable of running operating system level scripts) - you'd use **operating system** scheduling application (such as Task Scheduler on MS Windows).

Therefore (if on Windows):

- Create a batch script (`.bat`) which would ...
- ... run `sqlldr.exe` which ...
- ... uses your current control file and loads data into the table.
- Using Task Scheduler, schedule the `.bat` script to run on Mondays at desired time

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I am not aware of this process that how will I create a .bat, run sqlldr.exe . Any reference would help me to do this.

Comment: The simplest way is to put exactly the same SQLLDR line (you now use to load data) into a batch file.

Comment: Currently I am doing this task in DEV env but how will it work in production?

Comment: Why do you think it matters? It'll work the same (or - probably - even better, as production systems are usually more performant).

Comment: Okay but currently I am converting xlsx file to csv format and placing it into my local system and then giving a path in the SQL loader control file. But once this goes into production than converting to csv who will do this? And secondly, they will place the file into the share drive. So, how will all this be handled? Do I have to mount the share drive on DEV/SIT/UAT/PROD? Please advise.

Comment: I don't know who will convert Excel file to CSV; I don't know whether you can automate it. It would be the best if you could get CSV at the first place so that you wouldn't have to convert it. As of file location: it depends on which computer would schedule that job. Whichever it is (database server, your own PC, ...), it has to have access to that *shared folder*.

Comment: If I want to schedule this job at the database server then how can I achieve this? Share drive access we can provide but at the database server level how this can done? And also will provide the DB connection details for PROD right?

Comment: Scheduling depends on your operating system (on a database server). The same goes for a shared folder - you'll have to map it, somehow. To run it in production, then yes - you'll have to use connection string that refers to the production database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239231/discussion-between-vicky-and-littlefoot).

Comment: Still, I am confused with the term database server and the schedule is dependent on the operating system. How my requirement will be done in production can you give me an example, please

Comment: Scheduling doesn't depend on operating system; you'd still schedule the job to run at e.g. 8 in the morning, regardless of the computer. But - if you use MS Windows, you'd schedule that job using "Task Scheduler". If you use Unix, you'd use "Cron". The *tool* is different, the outcome is the same (data is loaded into the database). I don't have any examples; I'm on Windows, and "Task Scheduler's" wizard leads you through the process.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So, if I schedule the job in my machine giving the production connection details then it would work fine without any interruption. The only thing is database server should have access to a shared drive? Correct?

Comment: If you schedule the job on **your machine** (your own PC), then your PC has to have access to the shared folder. Database server (which - I presume - is not your PC) is in that case irrelevant, it doesn't have to have access to shared folder. SQLLDR should  connect to the production user (that's correct).